# How to get all possible permutations of string and all their substrings?

Tags: combinations, permutation

I am trying to find all possible permutations of a character string and all their substrings.
For example given the input 'abc' the function should return:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb', 'abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba']
```

I've been trying for hours on end and couldn't find any solution. Didn't find any related question either. A C# or Java solution would be prefered but it doesn't matter much. Pseudocode would be fine too.

Comment: You should probably pick a programming language, at least.

Comment: C# or Java would be preferable but it really doesn't matter much. Could be pseudocode as well

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually annoyingly simple:

```
static void permSub(String s, String pre)
{    
  System.out.println(pre);

  if(s.isEmpty()) return;

  for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
    permSub(s.substring(0, i)+s.substring(i+1), pre+s.charAt(i));
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  permSub("abc", "");
}
```

Output:

```
a
ab
abc
ac
acb
b
ba
bac
bc
bca
c
ca
cab
cb
cba
```

Note that the method outputs the empty set too, which is technically correct but you may want to filter it out.